# Submit a form with a hidden field that is a var from a calculation

Tags: html, forms, get, submit, var

I have a var that is the result of a math calculation which changes based on the users input.  I'm trying to create a get-form in html that will send the results to a new page.

my result appears on the page as var newpayment

```
document.querySelectorAll("#cart span.newpayment")[0].innerHTML = newpayment.toFixed(2);
```

However the form does not show the result..

```
    <form id="form1" method="get">
            <input type="hidden" id="submit_total1" value="" 
    name="submit_total1">
            <button id="select1">Select</button>
            </form>

    <script>
    var form = document.getElementById("form1");

    document.getElementById("form1").action = "/complete/file.php";
    document.getElementById("select1").addEventListener("click", function () 
    {
    var submit_total1=newpayment;
    form.submit();
    });

    </script>
```

Thanks for your help but I'm still not able to get it to work.  I've also tried another method by setting the value after the form is rendered (see Below). The var "newpayment" is displayed on the page as the span class but it will not populate as the value in the form. Thank you in advance for any remedies.

`

```
         <script>        
         function setVal(){
           document.getElementById('id').value=newpayment;
          }
         </script> 
        <p >$<span class="newpayment">0.00</span></p>`
```

Comment: your input value is equal to `""`. This way you're submitting an empty string

Comment: Try: `getElementById('submit_total1').value = newpayment;`

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm still not able to get it to work. I've also tried another method by setting the value after the form is rendered (see Above). The var "newpayment" is displayed on the page as the span class but it will not populate as the value in the form. Thank you in advance for any remedies.